# Refresh Fragment Him Self

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

It's possible refresh an fragment him self? Like an activity

```
context.finish();
context.startActivity(context.getIntent());
```

Answer (score 6):

I haven't tested, but maybe something like

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.the_fragment_container, new MyFragment())
                .commit();
```