# Android custom fragment transition incomplete when software keyboard is visible

Tags: android, android-fragments, rendering, transition, android-softkeyboard

VIDEO of the broken animation:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnPbEj-Wosg&feature=youtu.be
The original fragment has an all purple background, the target fragment has a white background, the transition is happening properly for only the top half of the screen.

Currently my android app runs one main activity and uses FragmentManager to .replace() fragments to change the layout.

In the initial fragment A, there exists a EditText which changes the active Fragment when "done" is pressed with the following code.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity()
                            .getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.right_slide_in, R.anim.right_slide_out);
ft.replace(R.id.frameLayout_main, fragment);
ft.addToBackStack(null);

ft.commit();
```

The above custom animation uses a pretty standard translation for sliding in and out:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="400"
    />
</set>
```

In addition, I am using the following code to close the software keyboard during the transition:

```
    InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    manager.toggleSoftInput(0, 0);
```

When this all happens, what I see on my 4.4 device is that the keyboard closes (slides down), the top half of my screen transitions (slides out), but the bottom half of my screen where the keyboard used to be is just white space during the transition animation period.

I have tried various other methods of closing the soft keyboard, as well as moving the keyboard closing code to before/after the FragmentTransition code.  Everything I have attempted leads to the same result as described above.

The solution I'm looking for is one where the part of the original fragment covered by the soft keyboard is revealed and smoothly transitioned to the next fragment.

EDIT: Tried android.app.Fragment instead of using the support.v4 ones and the result is the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517938/refresh-fragment-him-self

Comment: I am not trying to replace the fragment with itself.  I am trying to use a custom animation while changing it to a different fragment.  

I haven't tried it, but I assume I would have the same translate animation problem even if I were to replace it with the same fragment.  The fragment changing part is working just fine, it's a problem with the animation.

Thanks though :)

Comment: you need to close the keyboard before replacing fragment

Comment: mean you want to apply some animation while activity change ? and where are you addressing that animation file ?

Comment: @ImtiyazKhalani I am using manager.toggleSoftInput(0, 0); to close the keyboard right before the FragmentTransition code.  However the keyboard has its own closing animation which does not occur immediately (default android behavior as far as I can tell).  Both animations are happening at the same time, the keyboard slides down leaving an empty white space where the keyboard used to be.  If there is some way to tell the keyboard to close and *wait* for it to close that might do it too, but I haven't been able to figure that out yet either.

Comment: @chintankhetiya It is a FragmentTransition replacing one fragment ClassA with another fragment ClassB.  The activity contains only the fragment which is replaced as necessary.  The animation code is in the original question (the translate) and the FragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations().